# How to call PJAX on keyup in Yii2 grid view?

Tags: yii2, pjax

I am using common search in yii2 grid using pjax. What I want is to fire pjax on keyup event. Default it uses onchange event or onsubmit event.

**index.php**

```
     <div class="pull-right">
            <?=$this->render('_search', array('model'=>$searchModel));?>
     </div>   
     <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'assets','enablePushState' => false]); ?>            
        <?=
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
              --Coloumns--
                ],

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',            

                    ],
                ]);
                ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**_search.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php
 $this->registerJs(
   '$("document").ready(function(){ 
        $("#search-form").on("pjax:end", function() {
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#assets"});  
        }); 

    });'
);
?>
<div class="assets-search">
 <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'search-form']) ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => ['data-pjax' => true ],
        'action' => ['search'],
        'method' => 'get',

    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'searchString') ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
</div>
```

What I need to do achieve onkeyup searching instead of onsubmit or onchange event. Please guide me to right solution or give some useful link.